# Hero-image text property

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm creating a website with a hero-image. I've got the text in the CSS set to centre. I want to create another piece of text within the image. However, this time, in the bottom left. I've added the additional text into the div, but it of course is just taking the information I have set within the CSS (central). Is there anyway to create another tag within the CSS for this new bit of text in which I can set the properties to my choosing?

Here is my html

```css
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <p class="firsthead">test 1</p>
    <!--The centre text-->
    <p class="secondhead">test 2</p>
    <!--The centre text-->
    <p class="thirdhead">test 2</p>
    <!--The part I want to change-->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm very new to coding websites so I'd appreciate the help. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: use the class name `firsthead`, `secondhead` etc?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you just want to be able to set more/different rules on the `thirdhead <div>`. Right? If that's the case, then you can just add a new CSS block:

```
.thirdhead {
   ...
}
```

If you want to override previous styles from the `.hero-text` block, the new `.thirdhead` block needs to come after. In CSS, styles nearer to the end of the page take precedence.

Comment: But how do I make it go in the bottom left of the image? The .hero-text specifies that the text be in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

The idea to centralize item, you need to wrap it with a `div` as a parent, and add `text-align: center;` to div, therefore your child are centered.

```css
.hero-image {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1000x600);
    height: 300px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
}

.firsthead {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #D2691E;
    cursor: default;
}
 
.secondhead {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: default;
}
 
.thirdhead {
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <div class="firsthead"><p>test 1</p></div>
    <!--The centre text-->
    <div class="secondhead"><p>test 2</p></div>
    <!--The centre text-->
    <p class="thirdhead">test 3</p>
    <!--The part I want to change-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I make it go in the bottom left of the image? The .hero-text specifies that the text be in the middle of the page?

Comment: @HSmith `text-align: center;` in your hero-text defined align item to center.

Comment: @HSmith ok this is what you want? check the updated one

Comment: @HSmith wrap your test 1 test 2 with a div, div by default is block so it will take the whole row, then add `text-align: center` to it so your child is centered, therefore those <p> element are centered.

Comment: @HSmith oh wait you want bottom left, give me 1 sec

Comment: @HSmith use `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` in your 3rd text p, since your parent is set to `position: relative;` you are position based to your parent, use absolute and bottom 0 will force you to stay at bottom of your parent.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap, does this effect it?

Comment: @HSmith works fine with bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/Lmgokc33/

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, should I create a fiddle with what I currently have in my hero-image and hero-text properties for you to see?

Comment: @HSmith yes =D that's the best way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class .thirdhead in your css. If you place it after the .hero-text class it will essentially override the css used for .hero-text. Just structure it like this:

```
.hero-text {
   ...
}

.thirdhead{
   ...
}
```

.thirdhead will handle that specific element, while .hero-text positions the other two.